# How to copy container arg into environment variable in a pod template file?

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to copy the first container argument in a pod definition to an environment variable. This is my pod template file.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapp-pod
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: test
    image: nginx
    command: [ "/bin/bash", "-c", "--" ]
    args: ["sleep 30"]
    env:
      - name: "TEST_ENV"
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: spec.containers[0].args[0]
  restartPolicy: Never
```

But on executing `kubectl apply`, I get the following error.

`The Pod "myapp-pod" is invalid: spec.containers[0].env[0].valueFrom.fieldRef.fieldPath: Invalid value: "spec.containers[0].args[0]": error converting fieldPath: field label not supported: spec.containers[0].args[0]`

What is the correct way to reference this argument?

Answer (score 1):

Only a limited number of fields are available using `fieldRef`.

From [the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/downward-api/#available-fields):

> Only some Kubernetes API fields are available through the downward API. This section lists which fields you can make available.
>
> ### Information available via fieldRef
>
> - `metadata.name`
> - `metadata.namespace`
> - `metadata.uid`
> - `metadata.annotations['<KEY>']`
> - `metadata.labels['<KEY>']`
>
> The following information is available through environment variables but not as a downwardAPI volume fieldRef:
>
> - `spec.serviceAccountName`
> - `spec.nodeName`
> - `status.hostIP`
> - `status.podIP`
>
> The following information is available through a downwardAPI volume fieldRef, but not as environment variables:
>
> - `metadata.labels`
> - `metadata.annotations`

---

In any case, since the container arguments are available to whatever service you're running inside the container, you should be able to retrieve them from your codes argument array/list/argv/etc.